# How to switch view by locale in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, locale, laravel-6

I'd like to use different views for different locale in Laravel 6 instead of translate phrase by phrase.

Is there some mechanism or package that allows to do it?

Otherwhise how could I write my views and controllers such that it would be done cleanly and relaiably?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your views completely different based on the locale? Or you just don't want to add translation files. Because having to manage duplicate code will become hell pretty quickly.. Add `<div>` in one page and forgot on another..

Answer (score 2):

Order your views into language maps (e.g. the English view for "test" as `en\test.blade.php`, the French view `fr\test.blade.php`)
Then use a locale variable from your route to determine the view that is returned.
For example: `Route::get('{locale}/test', 'SomeController@test');`

```
public function test($locale)
{
    return view($locale.'test');
}
```